# How do I get my View\Edit tabs back in Drupal 6?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I somehow got rid of them and don't remember how. When I'm navigating my site while logged in as admin I want the view\edit buttons to show up above nodes.

Comment: Are you using a version control system? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be a few reasons.  First I would check the page.tpl.php file and look for `<?php print $tabs; ?>`. If that is not found, or is commented out, your tabs will not be shown.

Also check your CSS files to see if there is anything resembling:

```
.tabs {
  display: none;
}
```

I would also look for the use of [theme_menu_local_tasks()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/theme_menu_local_tasks/6).  For more information see [How to hide Edit | View tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3530756/how-to-hide-edit-view-tabs) and http://drupal.org/node/83090

Comment: I'd somehow removed the print statement along the way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using advanced admin menu (a contrib module), you may have allowed the option "display menu tabs in top menu" (or something like that) - in which case you'll see View Edit etc. at the top right of the admin menu, and not where you're accustomed to see them.

I once had the edit tab disappear on me.  I have no idea how this happened, but somewhere in the css it was defined as visibility: hidden.  Check your html to make sure it's not simply being nuked via css; if the tabs are there in the HTML, use firebug to find which css rule is getting rid of them.