# How to show a menu on a MENU_CALLBACK page

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I have a custom module, and I register the path in `hook_menu()`.

```
  $items['myModule/edit_profile'] = array(
    'title'             => 'Profle',
    'description'       => 'myModule settings page',
    'page callback'     => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments'    => array('myModule_edit_account'),
    'access callback'   => TRUE,
    'type'              => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'file'              => 'plannico.payment.page.inc',
  );
```

How to display rest of menu on this page?
I do not want to have this page in the menu. I just want to show rest of menu items on this page.

Comment: you just want to list the menu links in your `myModule/edit_profile` ?

Comment: what are the rest of menu items?

Comment: rest of menu items is register as MENU_LOCAL_TASK

Comment: hmm, maybe i didn't explained right. I have drupal standard main menu, and custom module menu with MENU_LOCAL_TASK items, and i register path to page that i don't want to show in that custom menu, and that works great, but now i won't to display that custom menu on this page.

Comment: `'access callback' => TRUE,` for a configuration form?

Answer (score 0):

I think that Drupal can´t do that using only configurations for menu items, unless you undo url nesting of your `myModule/edit_profile` and `myModule/edit_profile/nested_items_as_local_tasks`.

The alternative is modify your `access_callback` to a function who checks your current page, or modify your page-specific template and delete localtask section.

[Here tell how to remove the localtasks section](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6717278/2165413)